# Table View over a Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, tableview

1.can any one help me to place a table view on top of the canvas view. I draw a circle on the canvas and then want to place a table view on top of it. I'd drawn a circle using drawcircle method in a class which extends view.
2. How to show only 4 tablerows and add a scroll view to show the rest of the rows.

Comment: Do you mean the HTML5 canvas or is it android-only? I don't see the relevance of "in a class which extends view", maybe because I'm not familiar with android..

Comment: its android canvas. In the main activity I set as setContentView(new MyView(this));  The MyView class extends View in which I override onDraw and used the drawCircle method

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is really what you want, but here's a way (based on my understandings):

Instead of setting directly the `MyView` to `setContentView()`, you can define a layout XML file where you put your custom view in a relative layout, and then in the same RelativeLayout add the TableLayout.

I assume the package name of your project is: com.mypackage.
Let call the file `my_custom_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <!--  Your custom View -->
    <com.mypackage.MyView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!--  the Table layout  -->
    <TableLayout >
        <!-- ......... -->
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in onCreate() you call: `setContentView(R.layout.my_custom_view)`
Since both views are inside a RelativeLayout, the TableLayout should be placed on top of MyView.